# Kotlin Warning message and Highlighting issue

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code, warnings, syntax-highlighting

1. I installed the "Kotlin" extension in Visual Studio Code to write and run Kotlin code. However, when you I try to run the code, I see the following messages:

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true

2. Code Highlighting Issues:
   Most of the Kotlin code is underlined in red. Even those that are koltin keywords like println, listOf, Int etc.

I would be grateful if you could assist me with my current issue. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.